# SharePoint Service Application Account Change Powershell Script Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, spservices

I am trying to change the manged accounts for SharePoint 2013 service applications. Here is how I am using my powershell scripts

```
 $svc = Get-SPServiceInstance -Server DEVSP01 | where {$_.Name -eq "Search Service Application"}
 $svc.Service.ProcessIdentity.Username = "Domain\ManagedAccountusername"
```

I am constantly getting error executing the power-shell script.

> The property 'Username' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + $svc.Service.ProcessIdentity.Username = "Domain\ManagedAccountusername"

I have also tried

```
$svc.Service.ProcessIdentity.ManagedAccount = <Domain\ManagedAccountusername>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the service application name is `Search Service Application`?

Comment: Yes. It is the default one that got created with the installation. I have not created another instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If account is registered in managed account then try this for search service application

```
$MgtAccount = Get-SpManagedAccount -Identity "Domain\ManagedAccountusername"
$procId = (Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService).get_ProcessIdentity()
$procId.CurrentIdentityType = "SpecificUser"
$procId.ManagedAccount = $MgtAccount
$procId.Update()
```

http://tharindupg.blogspot.com/

Comment: Thanks Waqas...
That worked like a charm.  Do you think if it works the same for all service applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code as below

```
$svc = Get-SPServiceInstance -Server DEVSP01 | where {$_.TypeName -eq "Search Service Application"}
Set-ServiceIdentity $svc "Domain\ManagedAccountusername"
function Set-ServiceIdentity($svc, $username) 
{ 
    $pi = $svc.Service.ProcessIdentity 
    if ($pi.Username-ne $username) { 
         $pi.Username= $username 
         $pi.Update() 
         $pi.Deploy() 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amal. 
It just didn't help me though. Isn't it the same piece of code in a bit more conditioned way? Its not recognizing the function.

Set-ServiceIdentity : The term 'Set-ServiceIdentity' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At <path\ps1>

Comment: No if you check the where clause I am using TypeName instead of Name.. Have you tried outputting $svc object and made sure its actually loaded ?